# Android onclick listeners not recognized in drawer/sidebar template

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

On creating a new project in android studio, I chose the drawer template:

[image: Navigation Drawer Activity]

I began working on my project and in the XML file (fragment_home.xml), I added an onclick listener to a button in the fragment_home.xml
All the code of fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSomething"
        android:text="This is the home page"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anf then...
I went to the MainActivity.java file
and added two lines:

```
public void doSomething(View view){

}
```

So this is how the MainActivity.java file looks like

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    public void doSomething(View view){

    }
}
```

*Note most of the code is built in... all I add were the two lines before the last closing bracket.
Those are the only 2 files I changed. All the other files are untouched. But for some reason, in the fragment_home.xml, I get a warning:

[image]

Did I do something wrong, I clearly added it in the MainActivity.java. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doSomething` should be declared in the file which inflates `fragment_home.xml` i.e. `HomeFragment.java` and not inside `MainActivity.java`

Comment: It's just that someone else's appeared on the top

Comment: Yeah I think the newest goes first

Comment: For some reason, it says class or interface expected

Comment: Please update your question to show where you added this code

Answer (score 0):

Your **Button** and the method `doSomething` is related to **HomeFragment** as per you xml file `tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">`.

You have put the method `doSomething`in **MainActivity.java** instead it should be present in **HomeFragment.java**. Move it class **HomeFragment.java**

Comment: Thanks so much! I suspected it might have been that...